# Generate multilevel table

Tags: r, knitr

I've a tibble like this:

```
# df
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  name  town         pop lan     score
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1 A     London 15000000. english    7.
2 B     Paris  10000000. french     8.
3 C     Berlin  7500000. german     6.
```

I want to produce a table in knitr that looks like this :

```
London   15000000    A
----------------------
Score           7
lan       english
======================
Paris    10000000    B
----------------------
Score           8
lan        french
======================
Berlin    7500000    C
----------------------
Score           6
lan        german
```

Any idea ?

Here's the code to reproduce the tibble :

```
df <- tibble(name=c("A","B","C"),town=c("London","Paris","Berlin"),pop=c(15000000,10000000,7500000),lan=c("english","french","german"),score=c(7,8,6))
```

Comment: Are you trying to knit to a certain output format?

Comment: Check [etable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/etable/vignettes/etable_vignette.pdf) and [tables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/index.html). I think "nested table" may be useful search term.

Comment: For what it’s worth that looks like a very unreadable table. :-( I strongly recommend that you [read the entire LaTeX booktabs documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) (no worries: it’s short!) before you decide to deviate from accepted best practices for table formatting. (The idea being that you should at least know the rules before you can decide to break them. And, to clarify: breaking formatting rules is fine if it’s done for good reasons … but those rules also exist for good reasons.)